How to get enough RAM to allocate a vector too big
I recently started learning coding with R as part of my cursus in finance and my Master's thesis, so please keep in mind that I may be oblivious to some obvious answers or use of softwares and programming.
I want to calculate the impact of daily returns of stock and CDS prices changes on future returns.
To do so, and with some help from ChatGPT, I created a dataframe (359 710, 9   or 130 companies for 2767 days, and 6 variables + 3 indicators) with all my data to use in a Panel VAR model, using the function "pdata.frame" from package "plm".
I then use the fucntion "pvargmm" from package "panelvar=, to estimate the panel var modelwith my data, as follow:
> model <- pvargmm(
  dependent_vars = c("SR", "CR"),  # Dependent variables
  lags = 1,        # Lag order for dependent variables
  exog_vars = c("SPR", "VIX", "R", "L"),  # Exogenous variables
  transformation = "fd",          # First-difference transformation
  data = panel_data,
  panel_identifier = c("Company_ID", "Date")
)

However, after some time, it quickly gave me the following error message:
Error : Unable to allocate a vector of size 23.2 Mo
While I tried to free up some space, and looked for ways to increase the RAM usage for R, I either didn't succed, or didn't understand the other ways.
As such I would be very grateful if someone could help me solve that issue.

When I am searching, I use words from the error message. The search strategy for finding the duplicate was [r] memory vector allocate. It was the first of several hundred hits. Sometimes it’s necessary to sort by score to find better answers, but not in this case.

The 'Unable to allocate a vector' means R ran out of RAM. Close other applications on your computer (try a reboot), try making your R code more efficient, remove unnecessary objects from memory by first removing them rm(object_name) then garbage collect with gc(). If all else fails, try a laptop/cloud computer with more RAM.
